# Android WebView loadUrl not working anymore when AltBeacons RangeNotifier is set (in 4.4.4)

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem loading URLs (WebView.loadUrl) after I set the AltBeacons RangeNotifier to my activity. When I don't activate the RangeNotifier, my WebView handles every URL as it should. But when I start to listen for beacons around, every loadUrl call in my webview doesn't end and I only see a white page.

I think, this is somehow a problem with different threads, which try to use the webview...

This problem doesn't apear in Android 5.+.

Can anyone help me? Does anyone have same problems?

EDIT:
Thank you very much for your answer david. But unfortunately, that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

The following activity does not work on my Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.4 (the webview never stops loading! only from time to time, it starts loading, but never ends). I just removed all the code, that is not relevant here (thats why some methods seem to be a little unnecessary).

I noticed, that I get a FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed Error. And once, it worked fine (but not the other 100 times I tried :-/)

EDIT 2: I updated my code, so that my webview really should have enough time to load the url. I also load different URLs now every time. When I open Chrome and load the same URLs on the tablet, they load pretty fast (as expected with WIFI). I noticed, that I receive a "native on draw warning". I really don't understand this. On all other devices everithing works great. But on Nexus 7 with 4.4.4 this strange behaviours are causing me headache :(

```
public class Main extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
    /**
     * General fields
     */
    public WebView mWv;
    public ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    protected static final String TAG = "printr";
    protected AlertDialog mDialog = null;


    private Activity mContext;
    private int mCounter = 0;

    /**
     * BLE / Beacon Fields
     */
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = this;

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_webView);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Configure WebView
        mWv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.detail_ww);
        mWv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                if(null != url && !("").equals(url)) {
                    if(!url.startsWith("file:")) {
                        //show loading wheel on top of screen
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                Log.d(TAG, "FINISHED LOADING PAGE (" + url + ")!");
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        // Start Beacon Listener
        startBeaconManager();
    }

    private void loadUrl(String url) {
        if(url != null && !("").equals(url)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Load URI: " + url);
            mWv.stopLoading();
            mWv.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }

    protected void loadContentForWebView() {
        //maybe do some other stuff
        if(mCounter == 1) {
            loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        } else if(mCounter < 21) {
            loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        } else if(mCounter < 41) {
            loadUrl("http://www.amazon.com");
        } else loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");

    }

    private void startBeaconManager() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(
                    mContext,
                    "Ihr Gerät unterstützt leider kein Bluetooth 4.0. Die App kann daher nicht vollumfänglich genutzt werden.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                if(mBeaconManager.isBound(this)) {
                    mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
                }

                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            } else {
                if (!mBeaconManager.isBound(this)) {
                    // bind beacon manager
                    //Log.d(TAG, "Bind beacon manager.");
                    mBeaconManager.bind(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // settings saved for example
        switch(requestCode) {
        case Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                startBeaconManager();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        mContext,
                        "Bitte aktivieren Sie Bluetooth, damit Sie Informationen empfangen können.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        /**
         * Ranging
         */

        // Set custom scan periods
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(Constants.SCAN_PERIOD);
        mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(Constants.SCAN_PERIOD);
        // mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(60000l);

        try {
            mBeaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error setting scan perion: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // add beacon layouts for estimote, kontakt beacons, drop beacons etc.
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(Constants.BEACON_LAYOUT_ALT_BEACON));
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(Constants.BEACON_LAYOUT_IOS));

        mBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                Log.d(TAG, "counter: "+mCounter);
                mCounter++;
                getNearestBeaconAndPresent();
            }
        });
        try {
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region(Constants.MY_REGION_ID, null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {}
    }

    protected void getNearestBeaconAndPresent() {
        //do some calculations...
        presentContent();
    }

    private void presentContent() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(mCounter % 20 == 0 || mCounter == 1) {
                    //only load every 20 sec (with wifi!) - to be sure the webview should have finished loading...
                    mContext.setTitle("Counter: "+ mCounter);
                    loadContentForWebView();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy MAIN");
        super.onDestroy();
        mBeaconManager.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
[...]
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseEvent"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChooseEvent"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SetPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
    </application>
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manipulate the UI on any callback from the [AndroidBeaconLibrary](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), you must wrap it in a block like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // put view manipulation code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that receives the beacon ranging callback looks like this:

```
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            Log.d(TAG, "counter: "+mCounter);
            mCounter++;
            getNearestBeaconAndPresent();
        }
```

Understand that this code will get called about once per second when beacons are visible.   Inside the `getNearestBeaconsAndPresent()` method, there is a call to load a URL into a web view.  Even though there is code to do this only when `mCounter % 3 == 0`, this will still re-load the web view once every 3 seconds.

My guess is that not enough time is passing between setting this URL to allow the page to fully load and render.  You could try making this happen less often (e.g. change it to `mCounter % 30 == 0`, or you can check to see if the URL has changed and only call `mWv.stopLoading(); mWv.loadUrl(url);` if the url has actually changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't seem to be the problem. I updated my code (see code above) and wait for about 20 seconds, before I load an other URL. Same problem: the webview.loadUrl just doesn't finish...